# Recyclerview Header child visibility with scroll

Tags: android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview that has cardview header
I need when the recyclerview scrolls the header to be fixed but with smaller height and some of its child to be invisible how can I do this functionality

MotionLayout didn't animate child of cardview